# Performing numpy random choice only on certain type of columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains columns of int and string types. 
I want to add a column called 'MIN' and for each row, select the column name that contains the lowest value out of the decimal ones.

When I removed all string columns it works perfect, now I need to add a condition to skip the 'object' columns but everything fails - storing them in a separated dataframe, adding AND condition etc.

```
h_data:
size, price, facilities, service, country
9, 101,  6, 9, fr
10, 15, 14, 6, us
8, 54, 9, 8, il
```

```
-- This used to work when I had only int values
h_data['MIN'] = [np.random.choice(h_data.columns[x == x.min()], 1)[0] for x in h_data.values]
```

I expect to get a new column called 'MIN' which will contain the column name that holds the smallest integer per row.

Comment: how does the random choice fit into your description of the problem?

Comment: If I have 2 columns with the same value, I need to select only 1 of them but it has to be random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do a random choice, it doesnt matter which column populates as long as the condition is satisfied. Use:

```
df['MIN']=df.isin(df.min(axis=1)).dot(df.columns+',').str.split(',').str[0]
print(df)
```

---

```
   size  price  facilities  service country         MIN
0     9    101           6        9      fr  facilities
1    10     15          14        6      us     service
2     8     54           9        8      il        size
```